# So, while installing the requiements.txt file the following error shows up even after installing the req. files. Have latest v. of everything

Tags: python, deep-learning, libpng, freetype

```
 OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                   dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

 =========================================================================
```

=
* The following required packages can not be buil

```
                         * freetype, png
                         * Please check http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/pa
```

a
* ges/freetype.htm for instructions to install
* freetype
* Please check http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/pa
a
* ges/libpng.htm for instructions to install png
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem wi
pip.
rror: metadata-generation-failed